# "It hasn't get updated yet" or "It has not gotten any updates yet" or "It hasn't got updated"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I want to say I have checked the status for one product and there is no new update on it's status. Which of these is correct?

> "It hasn't get updated yet"

or

> "It has not gotten any updates yet"

or

> "It hasn't got updated"

Comment: I'd probably say "It hasn't **been** updated yet."

Comment: @stangdon: Thank you but I am also looking to see how to use GET verb in present perfect tense?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use *get*?  Overuse of "get" is a hallmark of English learners.

Comment: @stangdon: Cause I have heard "gets updated" , "got new update", etc many times and was curious to see how to use it in that tense?

Comment: got new update is just plain wrong. Updates are always new. "This is updated every week". Or: This gets updated every week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities, but not all of the suggestions in the question are natural, or even grammatically valid.

> - It hasn't get updated yet. [image: Red X, indicating invalid or disfavored form]

This has the wrong tense for the verb "to get"

> - It has not gotten any updates yet. [image: Green check mark, indicating acceptable form]

This is acceptable, but might seem awkward depending on the context.

> - It hasn't got updated. [image: Red X, indicating invalid or disfavored form]

"Hasn't got" is used by some fluent speakers in very informal contexts, but is grammatically incorrect. Use "Hasn't gotten" or "Hasn't been" instead.

> - It hasn't gotten updated (yet). [image: Green check mark, indicating acceptable form]

This is quite natural and grammatically valid.

> - It hasn't been updated (yet). [image: Green check mark, indicating acceptable form]

This is quite natural and grammatically valid.

> - No updates have  been applied (yet). [image: Green check mark, indicating acceptable form]

This is quite natural and grammatically valid.

Comment: The Brits use got for gotten, by the way. So, it hasn't got updated would be ok in BrE.